# Time is running backwards in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, stdout

Executing some pytorch code I get this message by stdout: "Time is running backwards!". What does it mean?

The program is running well, and appearently this message doesn't cause any trouble.

Comment: Maybe your computer clock is broken. Install a NTP service and/or replace the battery of the clock on your motherboard.

Comment: It can't be this, my computer is new and the problem happens both in my computer and in an external gpu cluster.